# Is method a class method or instance method

Tags: objective-c

In my code I want to know if a method is a class method or an instance method. The code I am currently using works, but I wonder if there is a beter way.

Current code to "detect" if it is a class method or instance:

```
Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
if (method) {
  __strong Class object = [[class alloc] init];
  objc_msgSend(object, selector);
}else {
  method = class_getClassMethod(class, selector);
  if (method) {
    objc_msgSend(class, selector);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your code could not be improved. You can change `objc_msgSend` to `performSelector:` if you really want but there is no real sense to do so.

Comment: I'm very curious as to your motivation here. Every signature in objective=c tells you whether it's a class or instance method so I'm curious why you would need this at run time

Comment: @NuclearGhost I want to call a method on a object which might not be there. This could be an instance method or a class method. Warren Burton why invert since it will only instantiate if it is a class method. This object file might not be imported. And this is a generic function to do so. I could make two functions, one for class other for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's very little that you can improve beyond two `if` statements. You can use `respondsToSelector:` method instead, but since you do not have an object to start with, you will end up with an `if` inside an `if` rather than an a better-looking `else if`:

```
if ([class respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    // Call class method
} else {
    id object = [[class alloc] init];
    if ([object respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        // Call instance method
    }
}
```

If you could modify your program flow to start with an object instead of a class, you coud do this instead:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    // Call instance method
} else if ([[object class] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    // Call class method
}
```

Comment: Method doesn't have a respondsToSelector

Comment: @MouNtant a method is a selector, an object has a selector. This is far simpler code than yours posted in the question which is overkill

Comment: @MouNtant I did not realize that you've got no `object` in the beginning. I edited the answer to start with a class method the same way that you did.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I feel like this code is basically the same and not much simpler. (Code in answer has changed)

Comment: @MouNtant If you start with a class, not with an object, the code structure would not improve much over what you've got now. If you could start with an object instead of a class, you'd be able to reduce nesting and shorten the code.

Comment: @MouNtant I made the same mistake, didn't notice the object init. Still think its cleaner and more readable in this manner. Also why do you keep switching between and upvote / downvote. Either way its still solid code